# R will not run after latest windows 10 updates

Tags: r, rstudio

I have updated my windows and R cannot run, and hence neither can R studio. When I run R GUI it just freezes and is unresponsive. I have allowed chromium exemption to the firewall

I am on Windows Insider program and has just updated to

`Windows 10 Home, Insider Preview`

`Evaluation Copy.Build 20190.rs_prerelease.200807-1609`

Note that R GUI freezes and then shuts down on its own, so maybe the problem is R GUI and not R Studio.

I get the following errors on R studio.

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Cannot Connect to R
RStudio can't establish a connection to R. This usually indicates one of the following:

The R session is taking an unusually long time to start, perhaps because of slow operations in startup scripts or slow network drive access.
RStudio is unable to communicate with R over a local network port, possibly because of firewall restrictions or anti-virus software.
Please try the following:

If you've customized R session creation by creating an R profile (e.g. located at ~/.Rprofile), consider temporarily removing it.
If you are using a firewall or antivirus software which guards access to local network ports, add an exclusion for the RStudio and rsession executables.
Run RGui, R.app, or R in a terminal to ensure that R itself starts up correctly.
Further troubleshooting help can be found on our website:

Troubleshooting RStudio Startup
```

Comment: Are you able to open R directly? Using RGui? (assuming you're running windows)?

Comment: No. R GUI just freezes then shuts down. I think the problem is RGUI not connecting to R studio

Comment: RGui(64Bit)(Not responding) ..... then shuts down on its own

Comment: Seems like that's where you need to start. Completely forget about RStudio until you can get R running directly

Comment: seems something may be afoot; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63436380/rstudio-not-connecting-to-r

Comment: A fly on the butter

Comment: @JohnKaruitha I've the exact same problem and I've been trying to fit it. From my troubleshooting, the problem is linked only to R on Windows 10 Insider build 20190. It seems to me that both Rterm and Rgui are broken due to a Windows 10 Insider bug or a major change. The same R installation works fine on the previous Windows 10 builds. So, I hope it'll get fixed with the coming Windows 10 Insider update.

Comment: @JohnKaruitha I'm experiencing the exact same issue, see https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-opens-with-this-site-cannot-be-reached/76490

Comment: @JohnKaruitha Would it be possible for you to add the `sessionInfo` to your question (eg. if the R console/shell is still working)?

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed with Windows 10 Insider Preview Build **20201** (released on August 26, 2020 in the Dev channel).The previous two builds were *missing 64-bit APIs* required by the prebuilt version of R.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.
Rollback to the previous version solves the problem.

I think it is about the update of the graphic features of Windows.
Here is what Microsoft said in the [build 20190 changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-home/active-dev-branch#build-20190):

> **Improved Graphics Settings experience**
>
> While this isn’t a new feature all together, we have made significant changes based on customer feedback that will benefit our customers’ Graphics Settings experience. We have made the following improvements:
>
> - We’ve updated the Graphics Settings to allow users to specify a default high performance GPU.
> - We’ve updated the Graphics Settings to allow users to pick a specific GPU on a per application basis.

Comment: Welcome at SO! Could you please add a link as reference (where MS is making the cited statement). THX :-)

Comment: After reverse lookup, I've found out the quote source to be [this website](https://www.techfeeddata.com/2020/08/microsoft-windows-insider-program-dev-channel-20190-1000-rs_prerelease-200807-1609/), which seems to be a summary of the changelog. The official changelog is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-home/active-dev-branch#build-20190) and does not mention exactly the quote in this answer.

Comment: NB: The 32 Bit version of R GUI works, it is the 64 bit that cannot run