# R 64-bit Version Not Responsive on Windows 10 (Insider Edition)

Tags: r, windows, pycharm

Morning guys and gals!

First and foremost, I hope everyone is well during these times. To be brief, I am currently having trouble running **R.exe (x64)** on my `Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview (20190.1000 Build)`. I have set the Environment Variable Path to the (x64) folder numerous times to check, but **Rterm** loads forever then closes.

I have gotten the 32 bit (i386) version to work, but I was hoping for any insight why this could possible be an issue. I'm open to all suggestions!

P.S. I should also note that it appears that the *R Plugin for PyCharm* does **not** work with the x64 bit version of R!

**EDIT:** My bad! The R runtime is v4.0.2. I also have v4.0.0 and v3.6.2 installed. Either way, in all runtime versions, only the 32 bit version works!

Comment: Please specify R runtime version.

Comment: @codez0mb1e My bad! The R runtime is v4.0.2. I also have v4.0.0 and v3.6.2 installed. Either way, in all runtime versions, only the 32 bit version works!

Comment: Have you verified that you are running on a 64 bit CPU? Also do you have an `.RData` file or a previously saved workspace in your home folder that be loading at startup?

Comment: This user also appears to be having the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457321/r-will-not-run-after-latest-windows-10-updates. I am too, and I'm currently updating to today's Insider release (20190.1000) to see if this helps.

Comment: To update, still broken in Build 20197.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! I am simply reverting to the most recent stable version of Windows 10. @tom